# INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE error during app installation

Tags: android

## What was the precise error message?

The error message displayed by F-Droid was on the lines of"The new package is requesting a shared user which is already installed on the device and does not have matching signature.". The eror code was INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE / -8.

## When did I encounter this issue?

When trying to install the app "Termux" from F-Droid. Essentially installing the apk and not from the Play Store.

## What have I tried to solve this issue?

- Search Stackoverflow for solutions
- Uninstall app / Uninstall App for all users
- Install App from Play Store and then uninstall it again

## Possible Cause:

I previously had the app installed from Play Store and then uninstalled it before trying to reinstall it from F-Droid. This is the most probable cause in my opinion although I **wasn't able to reproduce** it on another device.
**(Preempting my answer)** As it turns out /data/system/packages.xml still contained the shared-user entry for the app including the signature. Which explains why I couldn't install the other apk, since they were signed with different key although they're the same apps and opensource.

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved without root access:

I also encountered 'Error (-8): The new package has requested a shared user which is already installed on the device and does not have matching signature." after uninstalling termux in Google Play and attempting to reinstall it from F-Droid.

The phone was not rooted, so the solution suggested above was not available. However I noticed that some accompanying termux apps were still installed, namely termux API, termux tasker and termux styling.

After uninstalling them, as well as emptying the cache of several possibly relevant apps including google play store, google play services and package installer, I was able to install termux, along with the accompanying apps, from F-Droid.

Answer (score 2):

## How to solve it:

Warning: This is quite a **brachial method** to solve this issue. It also **requires root** access.

Based on [one answer](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1219029) on xda-developers by the user [tweakradje](https://forum.xda-developers.com/member.php?s=49ce56a58644876f28742601dbcc27aa&u=240712) I have found the following to work for me:

1. Copy /data/system/packages.xml to another location or your computer.
2. Edit it with a text editor and remove the  xml-block that has the the apps package-id as the name attribute. Example for the app ["Termux"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux) in this case:

   ```
   <shard-user name="com.termux" userId="10102">
     <sigs count="1">
       <cert [...]/>
     </sigs>
   </shared-user>
   ```
3. Copy the modified version to /data/system/packages.xml and overwrite the old one.
4. Clear the dalvik cache ("adb shell rm /data/dalvik-chache/*" or via recovery)
5. Reboot
6. Install the apk which should go through this time

#### Note:

This most probably won't work for system packages (those that start with "android", e.g. "android.uid.system").

## Further reading on shared-users:

- [Explanation of it's constraints](https://books.google.de/books?id=y11NBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA40&dq=error%20-8%20the%20new%20shared%20package%20shared%20user%20already%20installed%20matching%20signature&pg=PA40#v=onepage&q&f=false)
- [Android-Developer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element#uid)